# Trying to load a table into DIV from HTML file

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I'm trying to load the entire contents of a .html file into a div I have in another page using Javascript / JQuery and currently have:

```
$( "#divToFill" ).load("newContent.html");
```

However this replaces the existing content in the DIV with nothing and leaves empty space on the screen. The content in newContent.html is as follows:

```
 <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" border="0" class="results" id="results">
    <thead id="tableHeader">
       <tr class="column-headers">
          <td width="15%">1</td>
          <td width="10%">2</td>
          <td width="35%">3</td>
          <td width="17%">4</td>
          <td width="5%">5</td>
          <td width="18%">6</td>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr class="row">
          <td class="column">
             <div style="word-wrap:break-word;overflow:auto">CONTENT</div>
          </td>
          <td class="2">Num5757474747</td>
          <td class="3">
             <span>
                <div class="divStyle2"> TEXT TEXT TEXT </div>
             </span>
          </td>
          <td class="4">HELLO</td>
          <td class="5">10:00</td>
          <td class="6">To be done</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Any help?

Comment: You can try put this inside document ready: $(document).ready(function() { $( "#divToFill" ).load("newContent.html"); });

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: I have tried using the document ready as suggested by @PauloMenezes and this has had no effect on the result.

Comment: @KayVan there are no console errors to report. I wish there were, may have made this easier to fix.

Comment: try   $( "#divToFill" ).load("newContent.html #results");

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Still no results :(

Comment: ok again try $( "#divToFill" ).load("newContent.html #tableHeader");

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Ah! That kind of is beginning to work... I had only the header this time.

Comment: Good :) .. try to comment or remove tbody content and try again .. if it works .. check your code piece by piece to get the error .. don't forgot to use your main code $( "#divToFill" ).load("newContent.html");  without adding any Ids

Comment: Many thanks @Mohamed-Yousef

Comment: You welcome , Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

u can alo try loading it via php file

```
<script>
$( "#success" ).load( "/not-here.php", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#error" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>
```

if not try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            var includeDiv = $("#include");
            $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
                var href = location.hash.slice(1) +".html";
                includeDiv.load('include/' + href);
            });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery.load() function requires the entire URI of the page. So, if your developing on a live website, it would need to have....

```
$("#DivToFill").load("http://domain/directory/fileName.html");
```

Also, try outputting what the response from the load function is in the console. This will help you debug further. The way you do this is...

```
        $("#DivToFill").load("http://domain/directory/fileName.html",function(response, status, xhr ){
         console.log(xhr);
         console.log(response);
         console.log(status);
        }
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I don't think this is the problem. If I change the content of my .html file to just the word "testing" it shows up fine... showing that the file is being loaded but somewhere between the file being loaded and put in the DIV the table fails to show.